# What syntax is this

Tags: c#

I have seen this code in [NodaTime](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/DateInterval.cs). Here is the code here

```
public bool Equals(DateInterval other) => this == other;
```

This code uses the `=>` operator to define the body of a function. I tried to create a project using syntax but keeps giving me an error. I am using visual studio 2012. How can I use this same syntax in my code.

Comment: It's C# 6, which VS 2012 does not support.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodies-on-method-like-members

Answer (score 6):

This is an expression-bodied function from C# 6. It's supported in Visual Studio 2015 and above. You can read more on the [announcement of C# 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) (look for "Expression Bodied Functions and Properties").

Comment: `Visual Studio 2013 and above` not 2015? Once, there was an ability to use Roslyn with 2013 but currently that integration is abandoned as far as I know.

Comment: I have `Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4`, and this syntax **doesn't work**! I don't know if any additional configuration is required.

Comment: Sorry all, @nopeflow is right. The feature was first introduced in a Visual Studio 2013 CTP, but the first stable release supporting it is VS2015.

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool Equals(DateInterval other) => this == other;
```

is equivalent to:

```
public bool Equals(DateInterval other)
{
   return this==other;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expression-bodied function members allow properties, methods, operators and other function members to have bodies as lambda like expressions instead of statement blocks. Thus reducing lines of codes and clear view of the expressions.

Now in C# 6.0, instead of writing the whole property body using getters/setters, you can now just use the lambda arrow (“=>”) to return values.

For example, the below code returns the string “My Name” when you access the property “NewName”. Remember that, in this case you don’t have to write the “return” keyword. The lambda arrow (=>) will do the same for you internally.

```
Public string NewName=>"My Name" //this is the new way 
public string NewName//this was the old 
{
  get
  {
    return "My Name";
  }
}
```

Another Example

```
Public int NewSum(int a,int b)=>a+b;//new way

public int oldSum(int a,int b)//old way
{
  return a+b;
}
```

[**Link Here**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/857358/What-s-New-in-Csharp-Expression-bodied-Function)

Comment: You can use `Blockquote` when you quote something written by [some other guy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/857358/What-s-New-in-Csharp-Expression-bodied-Function)